# Display Multiple fields under solr highlighting

Tags: apache, solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I have fields namely uid, name, description. uid is the unique field and highlighting has been applied on description field. if a query is done, it returns the data in the below format.

```
"highlighting":{
"123":{
  "Description":["solr is awesome"]}
  }
```

The above returns the uid and the description alone under highlighting. I also want to show the name also under highlighting and it should look similar to this as mentioned below.

```
"highlighting":{
"123":{
  "Name":["solr"],
  "Description":["solr is awesome"]}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`hl.fl` : Specifies a list of fields to highlight. Accepts a comma- or space-delimited list of fields for which Solr should generate highlighted snippets. A wildcard of * (asterisk) can be used to match field globs, such as text_* or even * to highlight on all fields where highlighting is possible. When using *, consider adding hl.requireFieldMatch=true.

You can build a query like below :

http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?hl=on&q=apple&wt=json&hl.fl=name,description&fl=id,name,description

Please refer the highlighting link for more info
[highlighting link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html)

Comment: this doesn't work Sir. If i search for "solr" for the above example, am getting the name field under highlighting but if i search for "awesome" , the name field doesn't show up as there is no awesome in the name field. My requirement is that highlighting should be done in PageDescription field and  name field should be shown too along with PageDescription so that it will be easy to show it in the UI .

Comment: @UMAMAHESWAR : I am not very sure now about the requirement...could you please check with hl.alternateField.

Comment: i have already tried with hl.Alternatefield but that doesnt help . i have mentioned my requirement in my question itself . the first highlighted box is how i get the result now . the second highlighted box is how i need the result .

Comment: @UMAMAHESWAR : Are you querying on single field or muliple fields?

Comment: am querying on a single field . In this case, i am querying on the description alone.

Comment: I hope the name field is indexed. Could you try querying on the both name and description. Here make sure that both the fields contains the searchable data...